# Heroku Unexpected Token ??=

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord.js

```
2021-12-02T02:42:45.888858+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/APIRequest.js:33
2021-12-02T02:42:45.888875+00:00 app[worker.1]:     agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });
2021-12-02T02:42:45.888876+00:00 app[worker.1]:           ^^^
2021-12-02T02:42:45.888876+00:00 app[worker.1]: 
2021-12-02T02:42:45.888877+00:00 app[worker.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
```

I am receiving this error while trying to start a fresh Discord.JS v13 heroku bot.

My Procfile states:
`worker: node src/index.js`

I have added my .env and configured how the bot starts, instead of using npm start. As you can probably deduce, I do not have a `??=` anywhere in my code. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is APIRequest.js your code? Could you run it on a linux environment or docker to replicate the error?

Comment: @JRichardsz APIRequest.js is not my code. I'm not sure how I could run it on linux/docker from windows. However, it does run fine on my windows enviroment.

Comment: Is it a open source repository? Could you share us a mvp?

Comment: @ToasterBath27 please check if the Answer solves your Question and mark it as Accepted  Answer please!

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from discord.js and it's because you're using an older version of node.js. The [logical nullish assignment operator (`??=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) is only [available in node v15+](https://node.green/#ES2021-features-Logical-Assignment).

Heroku says that *"if a Node version isn’t specified in the engine, the 14.x release will be used"*. You can add an `engines` prop to your `package.json` file to specify the version of node.js. As discord.js v13 [requires node.js v16.6+](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#before-you-start), you can add the following:

```json
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.6"
  }
```

Or to request the latest v16, add this:

```json
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  }
```