# New discord.js update broke my bot - heroku not updating node.js version to make discordjs work

Tags: node.js, github, heroku, discord, discord.js

I updated discord.js to v13 and doing that it won't start on Heroku and keeps crashing. People have said It's because v13 discord.js requires node.js v16+, so I updated node and it doesn't work.

In Heroku it still says v14

```
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 14.x...
       Downloading and installing node 14.18.2...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.15
```

Here's the error I get in Heroku

```
2021-12-13T07:01:30.774733+00:00 app[Worker.1]: /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/APIRequest.js:33
2021-12-13T07:01:30.774751+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });
2021-12-13T07:01:30.774752+00:00 app[Worker.1]:           ^^^
2021-12-13T07:01:30.774752+00:00 app[Worker.1]: 
2021-12-13T07:01:30.774753+00:00 app[Worker.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
2021-12-13T07:01:30.774753+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
2021-12-13T07:01:30.774753+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
2021-12-13T07:01:30.774754+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2021-12-13T07:01:30.774754+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
2021-12-13T07:01:30.774754+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
2021-12-13T07:01:30.774755+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
2021-12-13T07:01:30.774755+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
2021-12-13T07:01:30.774755+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:4:20)
2021-12-13T07:01:30.774755+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
2021-12-13T07:01:30.774756+00:00 app[Worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
```

I'm using github to update the bot through Heroku and I can't figure out how to tell Heroku I'm using node.js v16+. If you need extra information let me know, thank you.

Comment: Does this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70193650/heroku-unexpected-token/70256355#70256355

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku Unexpected Token ??=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70193650/heroku-unexpected-token)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the node engine version in your package.json. Add this to it and it should automatically use this version

```
"engines": {
    "node": "16.x"
  }
```